# Dynamic page/content loading by keeping other content as static

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i want to load html page dynamically in my div element by keeping home.html page as default and on loading another html page the content other than div element should be static. How can i achieve it? please help.
I am using following codes...

html code

```
<nav class="main">
    <a href="home.html">Page 1</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Page 2</a>
    <a href="about.html">Page 3</a>
    <a href="product.html">Page 4</a>
    <a href="page5.html">Page 5</a>
</nav>

<div id="dynamic">
</div>
```

and my jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('#dynamic').load('home.html');
        return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: what is the result that you are seeing with your current code? what is the result that you want to see?

Comment: Did you inspect your browser's console? I mean does it throw any error on click of the links?

Comment: @danyamachine if i am not using returnfalse then its work like simple url and by using that its working after clicking on pages and i want that my nav should display at each time when i load other pages and want to avoid all content loading of home page at each time.

Comment: @Piyush yes i inspect that but no any error was shown on console.

Comment: provide a callback to your load function in order to find out more about the request: `$( "#dynamic" ).load( "home.html", function( response, status, xhr ) { console.log(response); console.log(status); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach. The loading target url should be based on the link that has been clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $('#dynamic').load($(this).attr('href'));

        return false;
    });
})
```

Please see sample [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/malcolmkee/wyro2uL7/1/).

Comment: it is not working for... can you send fiddle for more help

Answer (score 0):

To load the page specified in the href of the anchor:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#dynamic').load(this.getAttribute('href'));
    return false;
}
```