# Using LINKS to update page content

Tags: javascript, html

I have four tabs on my web-page (Home, Contact, about etc.). Each links to different pages. Instead I need to use same page and update the body portion alone. example: on clicking contact it should load a table containing contact information in body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor=white ID=body>
<header class=head>
<img src="C:\Users\HP\Desktop\HTML web\ProfilePhoto.jpg" style="border-
radius: 50%;margin-left:5px;margin-top:4px;padding: 0px 0px;"><h1 
align=right style="float:right;padding: -1px 
2px">GowthamSarathy<br>works</h1>
</header>
<nav class=navv>
<a href="#">Home</a> | <a href=#>Portfolio</a> | <a 
href="C:\Users\HP\Desktop\HTML web\conta us.html">Contact us</a> | <a 
href="/jquery/" style="margin-right:5px;">Updates</a>
</nav>
<p>Lorem Ipsum dolor set amet....</p>
</body></html>
```

Please assist me as I'm new to web design and interested in learning more.

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell without any code - what have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to provide some code what you have tried, so the community could help you. Don't expect the entire code from the community.

Comment: Duplicated. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733000/dynamic-page-content-loading-by-keeping-other-content-as-static

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic page/content loading by keeping other content as static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733000/dynamic-page-content-loading-by-keeping-other-content-as-static)

Comment: I think you're talking about a SPA (Single page application). In a SPA your requirement can easily achieve with the **concept of routing**. I recommend you to learn a front-end framework (VueJS, Angular,React). Your requirement can achieve by JS as well. But It is not the correct way to do this as far as I know.

Comment: Hi Thank u all. I have added the code. Can u all check

Comment: Can anyone give a short theoretical answer/explanation for my question(for my understanding). I will look into the links that was provided as duplicates of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad and is going to get a lot of different answers. But you're going to get into the realm of Javascript real fast with this train of thought.

Here's a popular example of tabbed content from [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp)

It makes heavy use of the "[display property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)" in css.
Other alternatives are setting the actual content of a div with an id, the example for which can be found at the bottom of this answer.

**W3School tab example**

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

**Replacing content in a div**

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The text has changed!";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click The button to change this text</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click to change</button>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```